# Pandas: Adding new column to dataframe which is a copy of the index column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe which I want to plot with matplotlib, but the index column is the time and I cannot plot it.

This is the dataframe (df3):

[image]

but when I try the following:

```
plt.plot(df3['magnetic_mag mean'], df3['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], label='FDI')
```

I'm getting an error obviously:

```
KeyError: 'YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'
```

So what I want to do is to add a new extra column to my dataframe (named 'Time) which is just a copy of the index column.

How can I do it?

This is the entire code:

```
#Importing the csv file into df
df = pd.read_csv('university2.csv', sep=";", skiprows=1)

#Changing datetime
df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], 
                                               format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

#Set index from column
df = df.set_index('YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS')

#Add Magnetic Magnitude Column
df['magnetic_mag'] = np.sqrt(df['MAGNETIC FIELD X (μT)']**2 + df['MAGNETIC FIELD Y (μT)']**2 + df['MAGNETIC FIELD Z (μT)']**2)

#Subtract Earth's Average Magnetic Field from 'magnetic_mag'
df['magnetic_mag'] = df['magnetic_mag'] - 30

#Copy interesting values
df2 = df[[ 'ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa)',
          'TEMPERATURE (C)', 'magnetic_mag']].copy()

#Hourly Average and Standard Deviation for interesting values 
df3 = df2.resample('H').agg(['mean','std'])
df3.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df3.columns]

df3.reset_index()
plt.plot(df3['magnetic_mag mean'], df3['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], label='FDI')
```

Thank you !!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df3 = df3.reset_index()
```

Possible solution, but I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529):

```
df3.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

But if you need new column, use:

```
df3['new'] = df3.index
```

I think you can [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) better:

```
df = pd.read_csv('university2.csv', 
                 sep=";", 
                 skiprows=1,
                 index_col='YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS',
                 parse_dates='YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS') #if doesnt work, use pd.to_datetime
```

And then omit:

```
#Changing datetime
df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], 
                                               format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
#Set index from column
df = df.set_index('YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS')
```

EDIT:  If MultiIndex or `Index` is from groupby operation, possible solutions are:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('aaaabbbb'),
                   'B':list('ccddeeff'),
                   'C':range(8),
                   'D':range(4,12)})
print (df)
   A  B  C   D
0  a  c  0   4
1  a  c  1   5
2  a  d  2   6
3  a  d  3   7
4  b  e  4   8
5  b  e  5   9
6  b  f  6  10
7  b  f  7  11

df1 = df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()
print (df1)
      C   D
A B        
a c   1   9
  d   5  13
b e   9  17
  f  13  21
```

Add parameter `as_index=False`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False).sum()
print (df2)
   A  B   C   D
0  a  c   1   9
1  a  d   5  13
2  b  e   9  17
3  b  f  13  21
```

Or add `reset_index`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['A','B']).sum().reset_index()
print (df2)
   A  B   C   D
0  a  c   1   9
1  a  d   5  13
2  b  e   9  17
3  b  f  13  21
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly access in the index and get it plotted, following is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))

#Get index in horizontal axis
plt.plot(df.index, df[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
 #Get index in vertiacal axis
 plt.plot(df[0], df.index)
 plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) to achieve this:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'num': range(5), 'date': pd.date_range('2022-06-30', '2022-07-04')}, index=list('ABCDE'))

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   num       date
A    0 2022-06-30
B    1 2022-07-01
C    2 2022-07-02
D    3 2022-07-03
E    4 2022-07-04

In [4]: df.eval('index_copy = index')
Out[4]: 
   num       date index_copy
A    0 2022-06-30          A
B    1 2022-07-01          B
C    2 2022-07-02          C
D    3 2022-07-03          D
E    4 2022-07-04          E
```