# How Groupby value counts pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ('a', 0, 0),
    ('b', 1, 1),
    ('c', 1, 0),
    ('d', 2, 1),
    ('e', 2, 1)
], columns=['name', 'cluster', 'is_selected'])
```

i want to count each letter selected in each cluster and group by cluster.
i tried this :
`df.groupby('cluster')['is_selected'].value_counts()`
and i get this output :

```
cluster  is_selected
0        0              1
1        0              1
         1              1
2        1              2
Name: is_selected, dtype: int64
```

but what i want is this format:

```
cluster  count_selected
0        1        
1        1             
2        2
```

please how can i fix it?

Comment: You say *in this format* - but are those numbers actually what you're expecting given the input... because I think may be after: `df.groupby('cluster')['is_selected'].sum()`... but that won't give you the same numbers based on the input

Comment: For cluster 1, should you not expect value count of 2? Or are you expecting sum of values?

Comment: That or you're maybe after `df.groupby('cluster')['name'].count()` but again - that'll give you 1, 2, 2 (as to the above which'll give you 0, 1, 2, while it seems you're expecting 1, 1, 2? Which is it? :)

Comment: Do you need [reset_index()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932759) ?

Comment: thank you for all your answer, i finally fixed it with the proposition of Gorlomi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation you want to count the letters that are selected (value of 1 in `is_selected`) grouped by clusters.

if that's what you're looking for then this should help:

```
df[df.is_selected == 1].groupby(['cluster'])['name'].count().reset_index(name='count_selected')
```

The output is a little different but then again I'm not entirely sure what would cause your cluster 0 to have a count of 1 in your expected output, so i hope this is it!

output:

```
    cluster count_selected
0   1       1
1   2       2
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give the expected output:

```
df.where(df['is_selected'] == 1).groupby('cluster')['is_selected'].count().rename(
    'count_selected').reindex(df['cluster'].drop_duplicates()).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
```