# Pandas copy index to new column

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I am trying to copy the index of a dataframe (`newdf`) to a new column (`temp_index`) using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932759/pandas-adding-new-column-to-dataframe-which-is-a-copy-of-the-index-column) but am receiving the infamous `SettingWithCopyWarning`. I tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379818/correct-way-to-set-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe-to-avoid-settingwithcopywarnin), which says to add `.loc[:, colname]` but it throws even more warnings. All errors are thrown on the last line of code; no errors come up if the code stops when `newdf` is created.

What's the correct way to copy the index? Would prefer not to reset the index, I'd like the indices from `df` and `newdf` to be agreeable. I just need the copy column for something else.

**Example Reproducible Code**

```
col1 = [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
col2 = [1,5,9,2,4,2,5,6,1]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col1, col2)), columns =['col1', 'col2'])
newdf = df[df.col2 >= 3]
display(df, newdf)
newdf.loc[:, 'temp_index'] = newdf.index
```

[image]

**Errors**

```
C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:845: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)
C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:966: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with how you are setting the `temp_index` column in the last line. The issue is as it says in the warning. What are you actually trying to achieve? To avoid this warning do `newdf = df[df.col2 >= 3].copy()`. Note you are indexing with a Boolean key which, AFAIK, creates a copy anyway so the above will not increase your memory footprint.
If you actually want to insert the index to `df` but only to a subset of the rows try

```
key = df.col2 >= 3
df = df.loc[key, 'temp_index'] = df.index[key]
```